# Get big data from API through POSTMAN, got error: <Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes>

Tags: python, api, postman

> Error: Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes,  but did not opt in to external sorting. Aborting operation. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.

This is my query body:

```
{
    "tbProjectId":"******",
    "pageSize": 5000,
    "pageToken": "*****",
    "allowDiskUse": true
}
```

pageToken is used to switch to next page because the max records for single page is 5000.

It seems I can only get data from the first 3 pages, When I try to query the 4th page, I got this error above.

I tried to added "allowDiskUse" to query body but it doesn't work, what should I do to get 36,000 records?

Answer (score 0):

Are you querying MongoDB? The definition should include the following:

```
@ApiResource(attributes={
    "doctrine_mongodb"={
      "execute_options"={
        "allowDiskUse"=true
      }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I never use MangoDB, I just simply write the query body on Postman, do you mean I should add the definition in my query body?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: But what is the service you are querying with Postman? This error reminds the one from MongoDB, so I assumed that. It is also not clear what is the source of the error. Are you seeing it in the response body?